# Rewrite URL with .htacess without changing address bar

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am working on a LAMP setup on a shared HostGator server. I am currently trying to create more friendly urls.

I need to forward addresses like this:

> http://usafarmtrader.com/posts/city-state/title-3869.htm

to here:

> http://usafarmtrader.com/viewpost.php?id=3869

without changing the address bar. My current rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*)? http://usafarmtrader.com/viewpost.php?id=$2 [L,NC,P]
```

Adding the P flag was the only way that I could get it to load without changing the address, but it seems to be breaking my javascript.

What do I need to do in order to make this work without breaking the js? AND
What should the regex in the rewrite rule look like to get the id(should be everything after the last dash) into that variable?

Here is my entire .htaccess file in case something may be interfering:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inc/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^usafarmtrader.com$
#RewriteRule !^down\.php$ http://usafarmtrader.com/down.php [R=302,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(js|img|fonts)/ - [L]

#RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*)? http://usafarmtrader.com/viewpost.php?id=$2 [L,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^posts/[^/]+/[^.]+-([0-9]+)\.html?$ http://usafarmtrader.com/viewpost.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^mylistings\.php|login\.php|myaccount\.php|newaccount\.php|reset\.php|newpost\.php|editpost\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^about\.php|contact\.php|down\.php|faq\.php|find\.php|forgot\.php|home\.php|index\.php|viewpost\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Google Analytics Integration - Added by cPanel.
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|(<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>)?</head>|<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>|i"
</IfModule>
# END Google Analytics Integration

# Use PHP 5.3
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `P` flag, since this is all on the same server, you don't need to proxy. Your pattern is close but also matches the **title** and **.htm** part of the URI. Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/[^/]+/[^.]+-([0-9]+)\.html?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @Helto sorry, there was a stray `)` in there

Comment: ok its working again :), but now I'm back to having it change the address :(

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon. I'm going to email HostGator and see if there is some setting on the shared account that is causing this.

Comment: @Helto do you have other rules? Or any `Redirect` directives?

Comment: I added the entire .htaccess to the question

Comment: I did notice that you had used /viewpost.php where I had the entire url, so I decided to try that as well. This seemed to forward without changing the address, but it then used usafarmtrader.com/posts as the base for loading the js css and other files instead of just the root

Comment: @Helto `http://usafarmtrader.com` in your rule's target is why it's redirecting. If there's an `http://` it will always implicitly redirect even without the `R` flag.

Comment: I see, how to I get the script files to load properly then?

Comment: @Helto The base is an entirely different issue, you have relative links, if you change the pathing, then **all relative links break, no matter what**. Add this to the header of your pages: `<base href="/">` or change all your links to absolute.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me, you saved me a lot of time.